# Airport Express as extender, can I use RJ45 to connect device to it?

Tags: wifi, cable, apple

So, my situation is as follows. I have a network printer without wi-fi support. I have an Airport Express set up as a wifi extender (i.e. it just hangs in the power socket, repeating my wi-fi network, provided by another device).

My question is - can I connect my printer to RJ-45 of the Airport Express and use Airport as a "hub" of sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. You can use the Airport Express as a wireless bridge *OR* you can leverage the onboard USB port to run your printer.

I do the former at home with a laser printer that previously didn't have wireless support.